# Enumerate All Finite Sequences of Integers?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I want to write a Haskell list comprehension to enumerate all finite sequences of integers.

I'm pretty sure that this set is countable.

This is what I have so far:

```
enumIntSeqs = [ (x, [ ( x, [0..x] ) | x <- [ x | x <- [0..x] ] ] ) | x <- [0..] ]
```

Another idea I have is to somehow list every finite path in the infinite array

Z* X Z* where Z* = {0, 1, -1, 2, -2,...}

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 7):

This is, indeed, possible. But it is not easy. Imagine you have an enumeration of all integers, an enumeration of all pairs of integers, an enumeration of all triples of integers, etc. Then you need to choose "fairly" from those enumerations to be sure to hit each element of each. A similar problem will arise when you try even to enumerate all pairs of integers. I suggest you start with that problem, and then look into something like [`Control.Monad.Omega`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html), or perhaps even [`Control.Monad.Logic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Logic.html).

Comment: Perhaps the most relevant is [`Data.Universe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.0).

Comment: Right. `universe :: [[Integer]]` yields `[[],[0],[1],[0,0],[-1],[1,0],[0,1],[2],[-1,0],[1,1],[0,0,0],[-2],[2,0],[-1,1],[1,0,0],[0,-1],[3],[-2,0],[2,1],[-1,0,0], ...]`

Comment: @user3237465, that does seem to be the most direct path. I'm pretty sure the others I mentioned will get you there eventually.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that even existed. This saves me so much trouble, thank you. Though now I really want to know just how the heck universe works.

Comment: @JohnDoe The [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-instances-base-1.0/docs/src/Data-Universe-Instances-Base.html) is not long, and if some part is unclear, the author has been known to occasionally answer questions here on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 4):

I am not going to spoil your fun by attempting a full answer, so let me just demonstrate a handful of things through the simplified problem of enumerating all finite, non-empty, sequences of contiguous naturals starting from zero -- something that you seem close to achieving on your own already. The key steps are already amidst your `enumIntSeqs`, but you don't have to nest list comprehensions like that. If you begin with...

```
[ {- etc. -} | x <- [0..] ]
```

... you can generate a new list for each `x` simply by doing...

```
[ {- etc. -} | x <- [0..], let ys = [0..x] ]
```

... and then returning those lists:

```
[ ys | x <- [0..], let ys = [0..x] ]
```

(Note that I didn't write `ys <- [0..x]`. Try to predict what would happen in that case, and then check it in GHCi.)

The separate `let` definition isn't necessary, nor does it add anything in terms of clarity in this simple comprehension, so we can just write:

```
[ [0..x] | x <- [0..] ]
```

And that's it.

```
Prelude> take 4 $ [ [0..x] | x <- [0..] ]
[[0],[0,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3]]
```

P.S.: Two other ways of writing the enumeration. Using do-notation...

```
someIntSeqs = do
    x <- [0..]
    return [0..x]
```

... and with a humble `fmap` (which in this case is the same as `map`):

```
Prelude> take 4 $ fmap (\x -> [0..x]) [0..]
[[0],[0,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3]]
Prelude> -- Or, equivalently...
Prelude> take 4 $ (\x -> [0..x]) <$> [0..]
[[0],[0,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, because your question wasn't very clear, but given the example that you provided `[0,1,-1,-2,2..]`, I'm going to give a few examples of how to produce a sorted list of integers, and change it according to your needs.

```
numberline :: Integer -> [Integer]
numberline n = line (-abs n) (abs n) []
  where
    line 0 0 l = (0:l)
    line r s t = r : line (r+1) (s-1) (s:t)
```

---

What it does is to ensure that there is a positive and negative number, with the use of `-abs` and `abs` as inputs, so that the line function returns them in that order. Then, you only need to map this function to a list of an arbitrary size to get a list of lists with integers ranging from a negative number to its symmetric end.

```
map numberline [1..2] -- [[-1,0,1],[-2,-1,0,1,2]]
map numberline [1..]  -- [[-1,0,1],[-2,-1,0,1,2],[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]..
```

---

So how do you change the above piece of code to generate an alternating path between integers as pairs of natural numbers in some array without repeating them?

```
countable :: Integer -> [Integer]
countable n = count (-abs n) (abs n) []
  where
    count 0 0 l = (0:l)
    count r s t = count (r+1) (s-1) (s:r:t)
```

The end result being `[0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3]` for `countable 3`. It's not very efficient for big numbers, so you may want to consider a list starting from the argument down to 0 instead of the other way around.

I hope that I helped.